# How to implement the context menu in iOS like the context menu in Android

Tags: ios, contextmenu

How to implement the Context Menu in iOS which looks like in Android. Please find the attached screenshot.
Please provide me some references.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a `UITableView` with animations, show effects.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done subclassing UITableview and add TableView subclass to current view.

UITableViewSubclass *subclass = [[UITableViewSubclass alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X-Coordinate,Y-Coordinate,subview width,subview height)];

[self.view addSubview:subclass];